# delete tableView data after clicking button on cell IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to delete a row in my tableview to update my changes.

I have a delete button in each cell (`tableViewCellController`) - look at the picture.
[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/4idq3aflv/)

After I click the delete button, the UI button method calls the delegated method in `tableViewController`. The delete method update the data source (my model) and i want to update also the screen (now the method reload all the data, but I want to update the new change - delete row from screen).

I tried to do this with the following function but i don't have a `sender` (as i said the button is pressed in the cell, but I actually make the change on the tableView)

Function:

```
- (IBAction)contactDelete:(id)sender{
    [[[ModelUser instance] getUser:self.actualLoggedUser] removeFavUser:self.contactUserId];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview];

    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
        [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

favoritesTableViewCell:

```
#import "favoritesTableViewCell.h"
#import "ModelUser.h"

@implementation favoritesTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)favoritesDeleteFromFav:(id)sender {
    [[[ModelUser instance] getUser:self.actualLoggedUser] removeFavUser:self.contactUserId];
    [self.delegate onFavDeleteClick];
}
```

favoritesTableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.actualLoggedUser  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];
    [self reloadData];
  }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)reloadData {

    NSLog(@"Favorites tab was loaded");

    //get id of my favorite contacts
    myFavListId = [[ModelUser instance] getUser:self.actualLoggedUser].contactsFavoriteList;

    //get data of my favorites contacts
    myFavListContactsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i < [myFavListId count] ; i++) {
        User* us = [[ModelUser instance] getUser:([myFavListId objectAtIndex:i])];
        [myFavListContactsData addObject:us];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return myFavListContactsData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    favoritesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"favoriteCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    User *us = [myFavListContactsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //setting cell data
    cell.actualLoggedUser = self.actualLoggedUser;
    cell.contactUserId = us.userId;
    cell.contactName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",us.fname,us.lname];
    [cell.contactImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:us.imageName]];
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    User *us = [myFavListContactsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    userDetailsProfile*  udVC = [sb
                                 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"userDetailsProfile"];
    udVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    udVC.userDetailId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", us.userId];
    [self showViewController:udVC sender:self];
}

- (void)onFavDeleteClick {
    [self reloadData];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to update datasource and delete the cell in your delegate callback that is invoked from your cell class (`onFavDeleteClick` delegate method of `favoritesTableViewCell` class, in your case).

The process should be something like this:

1. In your "favoritesTableViewCell.h", declare a protocol containing `onFavDeleteClick` method. I think you have already done with this step. What you need to do is to update the method signature as `-(void) onFavDeleteClick:(favoritesTableViewCell*)cell`.
2. From "favoritesTableViewCell.m" call `favoritesDeleteFromFav` method like this:

   ```
   -(IBAction)favoritesDeleteFromFav:(id)sender {
       [self.delegate onFavDeleteClick:self];
   }
   ```
3. Now in your view controller where the main `UITableView` exists implement the callback method like this:

   ```
   -(void)onFavDeleteClick:(favoritesTableViewCell*)cell {
       //update model
       [[[ModelUser instance] getUser:self.actualLoggedUser]  removeFavUser:self.contactUserId];

       //update table view
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
       if (indexPath) {
           [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
       }
   }
   ```

And this is everything you need to do to get your desired effect.

Comment: That is exactly what i need. But I get error: expected a type on -(void) onFavDeleteClick:(favoritesTableViewCell*)cell. @Ayan

Comment: I tried to change it to : -(void)onFavDeleteClick:(UITableViewCell*)cell contactUserId:(NSString*)contactUserId; but i get this error: exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: @jdoe Very sorry that I couldn't attend it lately. 
As a rule of thumb, your `onFavDeleteClick` method should do the following:
1. Remove the item at specific index from your tableview datasource.
2. Delete the cell at that index from tableview with `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation` method.
You are responsible to ensure that after the method completes, the number of tableview cell == number of items in tableview datasource. failing to do that will invoke the exception, you have mentioned.
So before you delete a cell from tableview, update your datasource properly to match the count.

Comment: Hi Ayan. I edited this question because it was not written with the technical writing that is preferred here. There are several community discussions about this, I expect [this is probably the main one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). Questions are [collaboratively edited here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). If you are not sure whether an edit meets community standards, it may be best to ask the editor, so that they can advise you.